# Tool to search opened window? (Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

I often have a huge number of windows opened and it takes time to find the ones I need. Aero Peek may help sometimes, but for some applications (e.g. SSH terminals), every window looks the same. And when I have too many windows from the same application, Windows won't show the thumbnail any more.

Do you know any software that can search the title in opened windows?

Ideally, I would like to bring up the search box with a hotkey, type in a string, hit enter, and have all windows matching the string brought to the front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run Switcher ( http://insentient.net/ ), which you should because it is **awesome**, you can do this by:

- pressing the activation hotkey, I have my switcher mapped to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- just start typing; the display will be filtered down to **window titles matching what you typed**. Only works on titles though.
- once filtered, press the number of the window you want or use the arrows to select it and press enter. Or the mouse of course (and remember that middle mouse closes windows here)

Easy peasy.

Comment: Thanks! It works. But it's kind of slow (with all animation disabled, it takes 2-3 seconds to bring up the interface). I wish it were open source so that we can try to improve it.

Comment: Oh the slowness was because I had too many windows. With only 10 windows opened the interface loads without noticeable delay.

Comment: @netvope it might depend on your video card as well.. on my machine it's VERY fast even with dozens of windows

Comment: I'm currently using an integrated Geforce 9300. Perhaps this give me a reason to plug-in my idle video card (it was removed to save power; I rarely play 3D games)

Answer (score 1):

Read up about [Vista Switcher](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/12/vista-switcher-better-windows-alt-tab-management/), it doesn't do exactly what you want but if you push `F9` it will sort the list of applications alphabetically.